# How to make the website has a fixed height and width with no scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website project to display a fake data chart and a website about crypto. But I was annoyed by scrolling on my website. I have used the 100vh method, but still in the mobile view the user has to scroll.

I want my website to run like https://www.thomaspeschak.com

where the website can display 100% of its content without having to scroll.

You can see the website that I have created here
https://yukcoding-trading.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following to the page wrapper (the `body` tag for example):

```css
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
```